# Why does setInterval() behaves differently in Firefox

Tags: javascript, animation, firefox, setinterval

I had to animate the rotation using vanila JS and encountered the problem with Firefox. I used `setInterval()` to animate each animation step and then `clearInteval()` to stop the animation. In this example I animated the rotation of an element. It works fine in Chrome, but doesn't quite finish the animation in Firefox, as if Firefox takes longer to process each step. I created an example, demonstrating this behaviour.

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle')
const angle = document.getElementById('angle')
const degToMove = 90 //rotate 90 degrees
const animStepLength = 10 // 10ms is one animation step
const animLength = 300 //whole animation length -> 30 animation steps -> 3deg rotation per step

const rotateCircle = () => {

  rotInterval = setInterval(()=>{

  //what rotation value currently is
    let currentVal = circle.style.transform.match(/[-+]?\d+/); 

    //add 3 deg rotation per step to it
    circle.style.transform = `rotate(${+currentVal[0] + (degToMove*animStepLength) / animLength}deg)` 

    //text output
    angle.innerHTML = `${+currentVal[0] + (degToMove*animStepLength) / animLength} deg`

  }, animStepLength)

  setTimeout(() => {

  //after all steps are done clear the interval
    clearInterval(rotInterval) 

  }, animLength);
}

circle.addEventListener('click', rotateCircle)
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#circle{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle" style='transform: rotate(0deg)'>
  <span>
    Click to rotate
  </span>
  <span id="angle">0 deg</span>
</div>
```

Also available as [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AlmostDeadDude/h8m7nz1L/61/)

While Chrome rotates to 90 -> 180 -> 270 -> 360 ...
Firefox goes to 57 -> 114 -> 171 -> 228 -> ...  in this particular example.
Well, this is basically +1 rad increase, but it has to do something with the selected values for `animLength` and `animStepLength`. If I select them differently, Firefox shows different values.

The simple CSS animation would work here but there are reasons for me to use JS here.

Comment: You can never guarantee that a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` handler will be called when you ask it to. You should always compare the current time against the initial time to figure out what kind of progress your animation should show. Using `setInterval` is considered bad practice because of that reason. The suggested way to animate is to use nested [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) calls

Comment: Iirc chrome does some (in certain details not even spec-compliant) adjustments, to make timers behave cleaner than they "should". The numbers on my FF are different to yours, in that they only lose 3° per rotation. This is less surprising than your results, which would imply massive dropping of timer events (e.g. because the computer is under heavy load, and can't keep up). Losing 3° per rotation likely stems from minor timer inaccuracies, or some other detail, which causes the last step to not happen before the interval is canceled.

Comment: Why do you need a separate `setTimeout` to clear the interval?

Comment: @SurajRao yeah, I realized that on a second thought. Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can never guarantee that a `setTimeout` or `setInterval` handler will be called when you ask it to. You should always compare the current time against the initial time to figure out what kind of progress your animation should show, usually by figuring out what percentage of the animation has elapsed. Look for the `elapsedPercentage` variable in the example below.

[Using `setInterval` is considered bad practice](https://dev.to/akanksha_9560/why-not-to-use-setinterval--2na9) because of that reason. The suggested way to animate is to use nested [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame);

The script below can use lots of improvements but it does show you how to properly update your animation based on how long it's been since the animation started.

```js
const circle = document.getElementById('circle');
const angle = document.getElementById('angle');
const degToMove = 90; //rotate 90 degrees
 

let rotationStartTime = null;
let targetRotation = 0;
let rotationStart = 0
let animationTime = 3000;

function startRotating() {

   rotationStartTime = new Date().getTime();
   rotationStart = parseInt(circle.style.transform.match(/[-+]?\d+/)[0]);
   targetRotation += degToMove;
   rotateCircle();
}

function rotateCircle() {
    const currentVal = parseInt(circle.style.transform.match(/[-+]?\d+/)[0]);
    const currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    const elapsedPercentage = (currentTime - rotationStartTime) / animationTime;
    let newVal = Math.min(targetRotation, Math.round(rotationStart + (elapsedPercentage * degToMove)));
    circle.style.transform = `rotate(${newVal}deg)`; 

    //text output
    angle.innerHTML = `${newVal} deg`;
    if (newVal < targetRotation) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(rotateCircle);
    }

}

circle.addEventListener('click', startRotating)
```

```css
body{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#circle{
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: skyblue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="circle" style='transform: rotate(0deg)'>
  <span>
    Click to rotate
  </span>
  <span id="angle">0 deg</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works great. I never animated stuff with pure JS before, so using `setInterval` was the first idea I had. The difference in behaviour in different browsers made this topic quite interesting for me.